# Why does bootstrap create horizontal scroll bar when using column layout without container?

Tags: bootstrap-5

The following page has a horizontal scrollbar. I know that adding a class of "container" will remove the scrolling, but what specifically is causing the horizontal overflow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                xyz
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the answer seems to be that "row" has the following sytle:

```
--bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
margin-right: calc(-.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
```

Which means the right margin is -0.75rem.

I overrode this value with:

```
.row { --bs-gutter-x: 0rem !important; }
```

But I still don't know why bootstrap sets a negative right margin.